# Android retrofit recycleviw item onclicklistener call other api

Tags: android

I have a recycle view that contain  information from API
After that in every item of the recycleview i have button that open new activity
This newactivity call a second API and have query parameter as an information from the first API

My problem is how to use an information from the firstactivity in my adapter directly because i have the new intent (that will open the secondactivity and in the same time send the variable to the secondactivity) in the adapter

```
 class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView code,description,emplacement;
    public ImageButton fils,detailsactif,serviceId;
    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        code= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcode);
        description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);
        emplacement= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtemplacement);
        fils= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fils);
        detailsactif= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsactif);
        serviceId= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.serviceId);


        itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsactif).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View itemView) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), details_actif.class);
                intent.putExtra("asset","zz");
                (itemView.getContext()).startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder)
        {
            Item item = items.get(position);
            String codeAsset = item.getCode();
            ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.code.setText(items.get(position).getCode());
            viewHolder.description.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
            viewHolder.emplacement.setText(items.get(position).getEmplacement());
//            viewHolder.detailsactif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View itemView) {
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), details_actif.class);
//                    (itemView.getContext()).startActivity(intent);
//
//                }
//            });


---------------firstactivity---------------------
Call<Modal> userList = ApiClient.getUserService().getData();
        userList.enqueue(new Callback<Modal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Modal> call, Response<Modal> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<UserResponse> userResponses = (response.body()).getmUsersResponse();


                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                    {
//                        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
//                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
//                        String code2 = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.code),"");
//                        setText(code2);
                        String code = userResponses.get(i).getAssetnum();
                        String description = userResponses.get(i).getDescription();
                        String emplacement = userResponses.get(i).getSiteid();

                        ImageButton fils= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fils);
                        ImageButton details_actif= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsactif);
                        ImageButton serviceId = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.serviceId);
//                       

                        Item item = new Item(code,description,emplacement,fils,details_actif,serviceId);
                        items.add(item);
                    }



//                    Log.e("sucess",(response.body()).getmUsersResponse().toString());
                    RecyclerView listeactif = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listeactif);
                    listeactif.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(listeactif, getActivity(), items);
                    listeactif.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: don't use adapter position as a unique id. Pass a unique id while adding the list in model class.

Comment: Please share some code, errors or warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save query parameter for the second API from first API as model in recyclerview. While clicking the recyclerview Holder pass the value from model to new activity as intent.put(YourValue). From the new activity read the intent and call second API

Save first API result as a list --> Make Recyclerview with list --> Pass model value to new Activity when clicking the button in holder.

Comment: I had The intent is in the adapter(itemviewholder or on bindviewholder)  but the information that i need for second call api is in the first activity.. How can i pass the information from that first activity to the adapter.. and then when i will had that information how can i use it in an interface because i have the second call api in that interface

Comment: You can call first activity value by making it as public and fetch from adapter or you can pass values to adapter